# IP Blacklist in PHP+MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, blacklist

I have been trying to implement a sort of IP blacklisting in PHP, where I store failed login attempts to a MySQL table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE blacklist(
    `ip_address` VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    `failures` INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
    `release_time` BIGINT DEFAULT -1,
    PRIMARY KEY(`ip_address`)
);
```

On my login check, I first delete any blacklist entries that have a release time before the current time (if the release time has already passed) with the following query:

```
/* I pass in time() */
DELETE FROM failures WHERE release_time < ?;
```

I then execute the following:

```
/* I pass in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] */
SELECT failures FROM blacklist WHERE ip_address=?
```

If I retrieve no rows or if the $row['failures'] that I get back exceeds 5, I allow for checking of the username and password. Otherwise, I reject the login altogether.

For every failed login attempt (whether through a blacklist rule or through an invalid username/password), I execute:

```
/* IP address is $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
   release_time is current time + (new failures * 90 minutes) */
INSERT INTO BLACKLIST(ip_address, failures, release_time) VALUES(?,?,?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE failures=failures+1, release_time=?;
```

Unfortunately, I'm hitting the database at least 3 times (clearing the blacklist, getting an IP address, incrementing failures as the minimum). Is there a better way to maintain a dynamic blacklist, perhaps writing to a cache every minute?

I did see that [Banning by IP with php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986154/banning-by-ip-with-php-mysql) is similar to my question, but I'm allowing for people to be removed from the blacklist if they stop attempting logins for a good period of time. This way, people who simply forget their credentials are affected less than people attempting to brute force their way into gaining credentials.

Comment: You should be aware that if anyone uses this on a shared line (university, school, library, anywhere were several people share an IP), then you'll ban the whole IP. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: @h2ooooooo This is true, although this would be true of any blacklist if I'm not mistaken (and feel free to correct me if I am!)

Comment: If we're talking about IP blacklists, which is definitely the most safe, then you're correct. You might want to limit the blacklist to a cookie, the IP + the userstring, or something else, however all these lack the problem that with enough knownledge, they can easily be modified programmatically (to brute force logins).

Comment: Testing [SO notification on SO/SE Android app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349288/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query doesn't need run regularly and could be moved to a cron job:

```
DELETE FROM failures WHERE release_time < ?;
```

This "boolean" query will return 1 if the person is blacklisted, 0 otherwise:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ip_address) as blacklisted
FROM blacklist
WHERE
  ip_address = ? AND
  release_time > ? AND
  failures > 5
```

It might speed things up as your not using PHP to count rows and compare numbers:

```
if ($row['blacklisted']) { /* ... */ }
```

I don't think you can avoid the last one really.

Comment: I'm just a tad hesitant regarding the cron job, mainly so that I'm not modifying the database when I don't have to (granted, there could be many wasted deletes anyway). What time range would you suggest? Possibly 5, 10 minutes? For the second query, I think you meant release_time > ?, so as to get still-valid blacklist entries ;)

Comment: If you have other cron jobs (eg. deleting old inactive accounts) you can just lump it in with those and run it on a daily basis. It's worth considering how much traffic (failed login attempts per IP) we are talking about here.. how many hundreds/thousands/millions of rows will it take for your `failures` table to become "too slow"? If we are talking high volumes and persisting these failures forever isn't important, you might consider storing the failure list in memory: http://www.bookofzeus.com/articles/validate-if-an-ip-is-banned-using-memcached/ (Thanks, fixed copy-paste mistake.)