# What are causes for not using limit on login page

Tags: php, authentication, login-script

I have seen few attacker attacking on my site and i came to know from one user that it is due to because i have not set limit on my `login page`. people are able to try as many time they want to login. I want to know how to prevent this and what they use to do so? so i can try and check my site. And please tell me good solution.

I am using language `php`

HTML

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <span id="other-info-font" class="label">Username:<br />or email:</span>
    <span class="formw"><input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" size="25" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span id="other-info-font" class="label">Password:</span>
    <span class="formw"><input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" size="25" /></span>
   </div>
    <div class="lo-button">
         <input class="white" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit-login" />
    </div>                      
</form>
```

PHP

```
require_once 'include/global.php';

$error = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";


//check to see if they've submitted the login form
if(isset($_POST['submit-login'])) { 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $LoginTool = new Tools();
    if($LoginTool->login($username, $password)){
        //successful login, redirect them to a page
        header("Location: index.php");
    }else{
        $error = "Incorrect username or password. Please try again.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that you can do is create "dummy" login input fields, then rename your real username/password fields to something less expected. Your login logic, then, would reference the new names of the variables.

The second thing that you can do is implement a delay on a login failure. While an attacker could simply refresh the page upon noticing that their attempt is taking a while.

A third thing that you may want to consider is creating an IP blacklist table. I had actually asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513727/ip-blacklist-in-phpmysql) regarding this a while ago, but to summarize it, it is intended to automatically reject login attempts from IP addresses that fail login attempts too quickly.

Your code might look something like this:

```
require_once 'include/global.php';

$error = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

//check to see if they've submitted the login form
if(isset($_POST['submit-login']) 
       && isset($_POST['emanresu']) 
       && strlen($_POST['emanresu']) > 0)
{
    $username = $_POST['emanresu'];
    $password = $_POST['drowssap'];

    $LoginTool = new Tools();
    if($LoginTool->login($username, $password))
    {
        //successful login, redirect them to a page
        sleep(1);
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        sleep(4);
        $error = "Incorrect username or password. Please try again.";
    }
}
else if(isset($_POST['username']) && strlen($_POST['username']) > 0)
{
    // Either autocomplete filled in a username in the wrong place or 
    //   a tool automatically scanned for 'username' and filled it in.
    //   In either case, sleep for four seconds.
    sleep(4);
    $error = "Sorry, there was a problem with the login attempt. Please try again.";
}

...

<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <div style="display:none"><input type="text" name="username" /><input type="text" name="password" /></div>
    <div class="row">
        <span id="other-info-font" class="label">Username:<br />or email:</span>
    <span class="formw"><input type="text" name="emanresu" value="" size="25" /></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span id="other-info-font" class="label">Password:</span>
    <span class="formw"><input type="password" name="drowssap" value="" size="25" /></span>
   </div>
    <div class="lo-button">
         <input class="white" type="submit" value="Login" name="submit-login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I am not sure if it will help me but i will fix the code in your way. lets see if it helps. i dont have any my own tools to check the hack so i will be not sure if its helping or not :)

Comment: If anything, users would probably be able to hold down the enter key and be able to make a login attempt!

Comment: i am clueless trying to figure it, everything you posted @ChrisForrence THANK YOU