# reCaptcha - brute force protection (php/codeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, recaptcha, brute-force

I am adding a reCaptcha field in my login form when failed attempt on the same username is > 5.
I'm having problem doing this without cookies.  If someone has an idea, it is welcome.

Here is my pseudo code :

User get on page, counter is set to failed_login=0

When trying to login, if user guess a good username but a bad password, the db field for this username is increased

When the counter is > 5, show a captcha on the login page

The problem I have is that even when the counter is > 5, the captcha field is not verified by my controller.  And also, A user may just leave my site and come back to have it's counter back to 0.  Is this possible to do without using cookie? I would like to have a simple way. If I use cookie, maybe check if user has cleared his cookie not too long ago, and display a captcha, any idea welcome
https://www.dropbox.com/s/30mf4ha1rm7w407/still_login.png

I'll post my full code below

**Controller** :

```
public function index()
{
    $data['publickey'] = "6LczHPd2USAAAAAbffN2Po1HaNqPyfdfdfdfdsRfaDPO9E-"; // for reCaptcha

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger">', '</div>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'lang:label_email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'lang:label_password', 'required');


    global $nb_failed_attempt;
    $data['show_captcha'] = FALSE;


    if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/topMenu', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/login', $data);

    }
    else
    {
        #check login
        $success = $this->User_model->checkLogin($this->input->post('email'), $this->input->post('password'));

        #sucess redirect to home page
        if ($success) {
            redirect('/');
        }
        # bad login, reload page with error message
        else {

            echo $nb_failed_attempt;  ## variable not defined even when it is global inside user_model.php?

            if ($nb_failed_attempt > 5) {
                $data['show_captcha'] = TRUE;
                $this->form_validation->set_rules('recaptcha_challenge_field', 'Challenge', 'trim|required|callback_captcha_check');
                # this doesnt get triggered even when >5, no captcha filled and with good pw you can still login..
            }
            else {
                $data['show_captcha'] = FALSE;
            }

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/topMenu', $data);
            $this->load->view('pages/login', $data);
        }
    }
}


public function captcha_check($string) {

    $privatekey = "6LczHPUSAAAAAKQ58YZoV8S8ZCZ6A4ZiuqxSbbK5";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('captcha_check', 'The reCAPTCHA wasn\'t entered correctly. Go back and try it again.');
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

**User_Model (db request)**

```
   public function checkLogin($email, $password) {


    global $nb_failed_attempt; 
    if (!isset($nb_failed_attempt)) {
        $nb_failed_attempt = 0;
    }

        #retrieve the user salt
        $query1 = $this->db->get_where ( 'user', array ('email' => $email), 1, 0 );


        if ($query1->num_rows () <= 0) {
            $this->messages->add ( sprintf ( lang ( 'error_log_in' ), 'not_exist' ), "error" );
            return false;
        }
        else {
            if ($query1->first_row ()->confirm_code != 'y') {
                $this->messages->add ( sprintf ( lang ( 'error_log_in' ), 'not yet activated' ), "error" );
                return false;
            }
        }

        $salt = $query1->first_row ()->salt;

        // check for hashed password
        $saltedPW = $password . $salt;
        $hashedPW = hash ( 'sha256', $saltedPW );


        $query2 = $this->db->get_where ( 'user', array ('email' => $email, 'password' => $hashedPW), 1, 0 );


        ### FAILED LOGIN ATTEMPT, increase failed_attempt value
        if ($query2->num_rows () <= 0) {
            $this->messages->add ( sprintf ( lang ( 'error_log_in' ), 'bad_pwd' ), "error" );  

            $nb_failed_attempt = $query1->first_row ()->failed_attempt + 1;
            $data = array ('failed_attempt' => $nb_failed_attempt );

            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->update('user', $data);
            return false;
        }


        ######## Reset failed login attempt if need be #######
        if ($query2->first_row ()->failed_attempt > 0) {

            $nb_failed_attempt = 0;
            $data = array ('failed_attempt' => $nb_failed_attempt );

            $this->db->where('email', $email);
            $this->db->update('user', $data);
        }


        ######### Save info into cookies #########
        $this->session->set_userdata ( array (
                'id_user' => $query2->first_row ()->id,
                'email' => $query2->first_row ()->email,
                'first_name' => $query2->first_row ()->first_name,
                'last_name' => $query2->first_row ()->last_name,
                'display_name' => $query2->first_row ()->display_name,
                'birthdate' => $query2->first_row ()->birthdate,
                'sex' => $query2->first_row ()->sex,
                'weight' => $query2->first_row ()->weight,
                'height' => $query2->first_row ()->height
        ) );


        return true;
    }
```

**Here is my table "User":**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `failed_attempt` int(3) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `salt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `confirm_code` varchar(255),
  `reset_token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `reset_token_expire` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `birthdate` date NOT NULL,
  `sex` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `last_ip` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_signup` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `os` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `weight` decimal(5,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` decimal(5,2) unsigned DEFAULT NULL

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

Comment: You have `if (!isset($nb_failed_attempt)) {` in your index controller - but `$nb_failed_attempt` doesn't appear before then. Where is it being set? This will always evaluate as being not set the way it is right now.

Comment: When someone is logging few times, you should not check the 'exact machine', but the 'user'. If someone is logging as 'john', for each failed login, you should set counter ++ on let's say failed_logins mysql column. If failed logins > 5, display captcha, if login success, reset counter. And that procedure for each user in db. I don't know how to do that on codeigniter, but the sketch of solution should be helpful :).

Answer (score 0):

You may use it without cookies. Some ways are using checking remote IP in table with all IPs and counting, or just set counter for `username` without checking cookie or IP.

`$nb_failed_attempt` for `index()` function is a global variable? If it's not - that your answer (`$nb_failed_attempt` not set everytime).

**UPD**

Start of `checkLogin()` should be like this:

```
global $nb_failed_attempt;
$query1 = $this->db->get_where ( 'user', array ('email' => $email), 1, 0 );
$nb_failed_attempt = $query1->first_row ()->failed_attempt;
if(@!$nb_failed_attempt)
    $nb_failed_attempt = 0;
```

Start of `index()` should be like this:

```
global $nb_failed_attempt;
```

Check also error messages and please write, if `echo $nb_failed_attempt;` work.

**UPD2**

I use follow structure of session table in big projects:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `session` (
    `id` bigint AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `login` char(128),
    `ip` char(128),
    `try` smallint,
    `blocktime` datetime,
    `sitesession` char(128),
    `firsttime` datetime,
    `lasttime` datetime,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

It helps save additional information about logins, enters, and help to users's support.

This table may be not fine, but it work for me.

Comment: Hmm I think I'm missing something here, I don't see how I can store a variable $nb_failed_attempt related to my user without using a cookie. By the way, i'm using code Igniter session system :
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Let's see. Condition `if (!isset($nb_failed_attempt))` always be true. Can you add Database structure to question? If you use PHP >= 5.3.0 function `checkLogin` will be generate warning or error. Read more on http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Try add DB query to select `$nb_failed_attempt` before condition `if (!isset($nb_failed_attempt))`. It would be work like cookies.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know passing by reference was going to be deprecated, i'll adapt my code so I don't use it.  Still working out to make this work out.. will update code

Comment: I now set the variable $nb_failed_attempt inside my DB request method, but even when it's global, the controller complains: "Message: Undefined variable: nb_failed_attempt". Thanks

Comment: Change `if (!isset($nb_failed_attempt)) {global $nb_failed_attempt; $nb_failed_attempt = 0;}` to `global $nb_failed_attempt; if (!isset($nb_failed_attempt)) {$nb_failed_attempt = 0;}`

Comment: Set `global $nb_failed_attempt;` in start of every function, where it variable need.

Comment: I changed for your code CnapoB, and added global $nb_failed_attempt; to the controller as well, it's working now. Only problem is if the user close his page and refresh, he will have the time for 1 logging before a captcha appear, I'm wondering if I should just made a DB request for everyone that get on "login.php" and see if there IP is on a block list, may be overkill tough...

Comment: Please check, that `$nb_failed_attempt` increase even if captcha showing. Try it do without IP blocklist, it should be work well.

Comment: Yes it increase, see here :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lepcmuqczyp135e/7attempt.png 
the problem if the user close the page, and open a new one, it doesn't show the captcha : https://www.dropbox.com/s/m0snvpqvsmhis9c/afterRefreshPage.png

Comment: It's work fine. You don't know, who is came to site (his e-mail) first time. You may check his IP address to get him captcha first time. Unfortunately I can't see your previously big comment full. IP block list not crash or overkill your DB, if it contain only two columns (UNIQUE IP and COUNT).

Comment: You also may save last user e-mail in cookies - it improve login page and help user to fill it in future.

Comment: Please see UPD2 in answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I've decided to throw out this concept and instead use a blacklist of IP in a different table, like this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513727/ip-blacklist-in-phpmysql